# Is it possible to have a composed name table?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We inherit a database and we need to do an API to communicate with it. We are considering the possibility to use JPA / Hibernate, but there is maybe a blocking constraint.

To facilitate maintenance, our predecessors have split a table into multiple with a business parameter.
So, there are some tables named ELEMENT_xxx where xxx is a specific name.

Is it possible to make a JPA entity with a constructor which take the specific name in parameter and then allow to query on the right table?

Thank you

PS: 
If not, i think the solution could be to create an entity for each table. But we don't know how many tables they have, and we understood that they can create new.

Comment: If it's feasable you could use native queries with table name composed as String based on constructor argument. Not exactly a pretty thing, but should work better than mapping an unknown amount of tables.

Comment: So, doing JPA with only SQL requests ? is it not easier to do that with JDBC Template directly ? or is it interesting to use JPA in order to have the object schema ?

Comment: I have no experience with JDBC Template, however it seems to me that while that part of the database would only use low level SQL requests in DAO that JDBC template might do equally well you will have pretty JPA entities in the remaining part of your API (and there are more tables than just those ELEMENT_xxx right?). Also note, that I did not add that as an answer, I do not know if such mappings are possible, that is just the way I did it the last time I encountered dynamic tables.

Comment: There are not only ELEMENT_XXX. Each ELEMENT_XXX has subtables (ATTRIBUT_xxx, STATE_xxx). So i dont think it is possible to use JPA. It is working if we request with SQL each time. But what will it happen if we have a list of attributes in element, and we modify it then save the element. EntityManager will try to update ATTRIBUT table. It will request on ELEMENT not ELEMENT_XXX...